# Installing Nodejs v8.2.1 in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

How to install Nodejs v8.2.1 in Ubuntu 17.04. When I give the command 'sudo app install nodejs' the version that gets installed is v4.7.2. - Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Node Version Manager NVM

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
$ nvm install node
$ node -v
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a good article from NodeJS itself (found by searching for "install node js ubuntu"). You can find it [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)

You just need to execute the following commands to get the newest NodeJS version.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I would also suggest installing nvm so you could run multiple NodeJS versions side by side.

Comment: I was getting install errors. Was able to install using NVM. Thx for the interesting article.

Comment: No worries :) Maybe it didn't remove the system nodejs correctly though. But i'm glad it worked with nvm.